# Angular Forms create control for each property of object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material-6

I am trying to create an angular form array which contains multiple objects and each object has 5 properties. I retrieve the array of objects from firestore and i pass it to the form group, what i am struggling with is how to add controls for each distinct object and its properties. I have attached the snippet of what i have so far.

the first pic is of the array of objects that i passed to my form which i printed in html using

```
{{m1t1Form.value | json}}

Value: { "players": [ { "kills": 0, "deaths": 0, "damage": 0, "id": "JVnUQRv1YBt9D7JIkWvn", "playerID": "dAS3YyQvTX8ILQQPRxO3" }, { "kills": 0, "deaths": 0, "damage": 0, "id": "OwFBLDgQxDv86TiA2Urc", "playerID": "8ZCqn1NEqPSFchoPjigY" }, { "kills": 0, "deaths": 0, "damage": 0, "id": "UBnQmwiRJwF2HgNYvqGn", "playerID": "xkGVBqn3Pv50vVa5iiO1" }, { "kills": 0, "deaths": 0, "damage": 0, "id": "q4kHgwENnVTuvEIRUpUe", "playerID": "qmKJc03aqmfgAWrZQRzO" }, { "kills": 0, "deaths": 0, "damage": 0, "id": "qh8ZKPLpd64Cq4Ixw6Aa", "playerID": "OLJr4qvdOlFgIcb66iSI" } ] }
```

[image: ex1]
[image: ex2]
[image: ex3]

Comment: You can use dynamic forms to add controls to your form on runtime. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: It is possible, but I have a question. Do you want any validation on array properties or just plain binding? 
Please provide the json result in text format instead of image, so that I can create sample for you.

Comment: @AjayOjha i will be adding validation later but right now just binding would be fine i guess. also edited the json as text

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will update you soon.

Comment: Do you also want control dynamic ? ie. kills, death, damage ?

Comment: yeah like it would be perfect if the binding is similar to what patchvalue binding. I need controls for those 3 properties and a way to access the id and playerID properties in a function call to update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having same functionality. Below code will help you.

**HTML Code :**

```
                                      <form [formGroup]="m1t1Form" class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    <div formArrayName="players" *ngFor="let player of m1t1Form.get('players').controls; let i = index;">
                                                        <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                <input class="form-control col-md-5" formControlName="kills" placeholder="kills">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                <input type="text" placeholder="death" class="form-control col-md-5"
                                                                 formControlName="death">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs m-t-sm" type="button" (click)="getPlayerDetails(i)">
                                                                <i name="save" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

**TS Code :**

```
    m1t1Form: FormGroup;
    players: FormArray;

    ngOnInit(){

       // Default adding one object
       this.m1t1Form= new FormGroup({
            'players': new FormArray([this.createItem()])
        });

        // Load you data from  service
        let playersData : any[] = []; // Fille data

        // Create control dynamically and set value from service data to form
        if (playersData .length > 0) {
            this.players= this.m1t1Form.get('players') as FormArray;
            while (this.players.length) {
               this.players.removeAt(0);
            }
            this.m1t1Form.patchValue(this.playersData );
            playersData .forEach(player=> 
            this.players.push(this.formBuilder.group(player)));
         }
      }

      createItem(): FormGroup {
          return new FormGroup({
            id: new FormControl(),
            kills: new FormControl(),
            death: new FormControl()
          });
       }


   getPlayerDetails(index: any) {
        if (this.players.at(index).get('id').value) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with id or playerId
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there somewhere i can pass the player.id as a parameter to a function call with this? also i got similar functionality working with different code and idk which is better

Comment: You can add all your fields to `createItem()` method, it will be bind to your form.

Comment: i meant more in like i want to sent the player.id in a (click) function of a button so how can i get that value

Comment: its saying cannot read property at of undefined, maybe because when i retrieve the data in this.players its in a subscribe call and i guess outside the subscribe it doesnt exist?

Comment: Do you know how i can disable any of the controls? i tried new FormControl({disable:true}) but didnt work

Comment: Try disabled:true instead of disable:true.

Comment: didnt work, i just used hardcoded {{}} expression value

Comment: Ideally this should work : FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}). But anyways that is also not an issue if you add in HTML like you did.

Answer (score 3):

Hi This might be helpful for you for binding your form which I have used in my project.

```
constructor(  private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
{
    this.m1t1Form = formBuilder.group({
      'players' : formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }
}


ngAfterViewInit()
{
        for (let i = 0; i < valueObject.players.length; i++) 
        {
            const control = <FormArray>this.m1t1Form.controls['players'];
            control.push(this.initPlayerForm(valueObject.players[i]));
        }
}

initPlayerForm(playerVO : player)
{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'kills': [player.kills],
      'death': [player.death],
      'damage': [player.damage],
      'id': [player.id],
      'playerId': [player.playerId]
    });
}
```

By this way you can bind your form dynamically with any number of players. It is also helpful for you to add validations.